# Google Crendentials in NULL and I cant set the environmental variable

Tags: google-translate

I'm trying to translate text box text using ASP.Net. While integrating Google translate API i'm getting in TranslationClient.Create(). and in metadata file the translation client is null.Even i set credentials path in environmental variable but still it is null..How to resolved it?

```
 TranslationClient Client = TranslationClient.Create();
    var text = txtCategoryName.Text;
    var resp = Client.TranslateText(text, LanguageCodes.English, LanguageCodes.ChineseSimplified);

*Meta DATA file*
public static TranslationClient Create(GoogleCredential credential = null, TranslationModel model = TranslationModel.ServiceDefault);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Asynchronously creates a Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationClient, using
    //     application default credentials if no credentials are specified.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   credential:
    //     Optional Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.
    //
    //   model:
    //     The default translation model to use. Defaults to Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationModel.ServiceDefault.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The task representing the created Google.Cloud.Translation.V2.TranslationClient.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The credentials are scoped as necessary.
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<CreateAsync>d__19))]
    public static Task<TranslationClient> CreateAsync(GoogleCredential credential = null, TranslationModel model = TranslationModel.ServiceDefault);
```

Actual Result is null in translation client instead on translated text

[Highlighted line in this image is showing null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofEzG.png)

[Meta Data File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgX4Y.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "in metadata file the translation client is null"? The default value for the `GoogleCredential` parameter is null, but that's not the same thing as it being null at execution time. Could you clarify *exactly* what you're seeing?

Comment: (Also please specify exactly how you're setting the environment variable. It's easy to set it in one place where it won't be picked up in your application. You may find it useful to log the value *from your code* so you can at least see when it's being picked up.)

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet , I have updated the question. Can you please look into it? and i have provided the links for images as well.

Comment: What you've shown is that the default value of the *parameter* is null. That's expected. (If it's null, we use the application default credentials.) The line you've highlighted just shows a call to `TranslationClient.Create` - that will *not* return null, ever. I'm still very confused as to what you believe is null at execution time.